# Time Series Dataframe Groupby 3d Array - observation/row count - For LSTM

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, time-series, lstm

I have a time series with a structure like below, and identifier column and two value columns (floats)

dataframe called just df:

```
Date          Id    Value1    Value2
2014-10-01     A      1.1       1.2
2014-10-01     B      1.3       1.4
2014-10-02     A      1.5       1.6
2014-10-02     B      1.7       1.8
2014-10-03     A      3.2       4.8
2014-10-03     B      8.2       10.1
2014-10-04     A      6.1       7.2
2014-10-04     B      4.3       4.1
```

What I am trying to do is turn it into a an array that is grouped by the identifier column with a rolling 3 observation period so I would end up with is this:

```
[[[1.1 1.2]
  [1.5 1.6]   '----> ID A 10/1 to 10/3'
  [3.2 4.8]]

 [[1.3  1.4]
  [1.7  1.8]   '----> ID B 10/1 to 10/3'
  [8.2 10.1]]

 [[1.5 1.6]
  [3.2 4.8]   '----> ID A 10/2 to 10/4'
  [6.1 7.2]] 
  
 [[1.7  1.8]
  [8.2 10.1]  '----> ID B 10/2 to 10/4'
  [4.3  4.1]]]
```

Of course ignore the parts in quotes above in the array but you hopefully get the idea.
I have a larger dataset that has more identifiers and may need to change the observation count, so can't hard the row count.  So far the direction I am leaning towards is taking the unique values of the ID column and iterating and grabbing 3 values at a time, by creating a temp df and iterating over that.
Seems there is probably a better and faster way to do this.

"pseudo code"

```
unique_ids = df.ID.unique().tolist()

for id in unique_ids:
    temp_df = df.loc[df['Id']==id]]
```

Though the part am I stuck on there is the best way to iterate over the temp_df as well.

The end output would be used in an LSTM model; however most other solutions are written to not need to handle the groupby aspect as with column 'Id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redoing this a bit to make it more dynamic for the columns and keep the time series in order, also added a target array as well to keep the predictions in order.  For anyone that needs this here is the function:

```
def data_to_array_steps(array_steps_df, time_steps, columns_to_array, id_column):
"""
https: //www.mikulskibartosz.name/ how - to - turn - pandas - data - frame - into - time - series - input - for -rnn /
:param array_steps_df: the dataframe from the csv
:param time_steps: how many time steps
:param columns_to_array: what columns to convert to the array
:param id_column: what is to be used for the identifier
:return: data grouped in a # observations by identifier and date
"""

    id_list = array_steps_df[id_column].unique().tolist()
    date_list = array_steps_df['date'].unique().tolist()

    master_list = []
    target_list = []

    missing_counter = 0
    total_counter = 0

    # grab date size = time steps at a time and iterate through all of them
    for date in range(len(date_list) - time_steps + 1):
        date_range_test = date_list[date:time_steps+date]

        date_range_df = array_steps_df.loc[(array_steps_df['date'] <= date_range_test[-1]) &
                                           (array_steps_df['date'] >= date_range_test[0])
                                          ]

        # for each id do it separately so time series data doesn't get mixed up
        for identifier in id_list:

            # get id in here and then skip if not the required time steps/observations for the id

            date_range_id = date_range_df.loc[date_range_df[id_column] == identifier]

            master_dict = {}

        # if there aren't enough observations for the data range
            if len(date_range_id) != time_steps:

                # dont fully need the counter except in unusual circumstances when debugging it causes no harm for now
                missing_counter += 1

            else:
            # add target each loop through for the last date in the date range for the id or ticker
                target = array_steps_df['target'].\
                         loc[(array_steps_df['date'] == date_range_test[-1])
                           & (array_steps_df[id_column] == identifier)                                     
                            ].iloc[0]

                target_list.append(target)

                total_counter += 1

                # loop through each column in dataframe
                for column in columns_to_array:

                    date_range_id_value = date_range_id[[column]].values

                    master_dict[column] = []
                    master_dict[column].append(date_range_id_value)

                master_list.append(master_dict)

    # redo columns to arrays, after they have been ordered and grouped by Id above
    array_list = []

    # for each column go through the values in the array create an array for the column then append to list
    for column in columns_to_array:

        for idx, dic in enumerate(master_list):
            # init arrays here if the first value
            if idx == 0:
                 value_array_init = master_list[0][column]

            else:
                 value_array_init += master_list[idx][column]

        array_list.append(np.array(value_array_init))

    # for each value in the array list, horizontally stack each value
    all_array = np.hstack(array_list).reshape((total_counter,
                                               len(columns_to_array),
                                               time_steps
                                               )
                                             ).transpose(0, 2, 1)

    target_array_all = np.array(target_list
                                ).reshape(len(target_list),
                                          1)

    # should probably make this an if condition later after a few more tests
    print('check of length of arrays', len(all_array), len(target_array_all))

    return all_array, target_array_all
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing for the solution, not the pretty easiest but then again my question wasn't winning any beauty contests to begin with

```
id_list = array_steps_df['Id'].unique().tolist()

# change number of steps as needed
step = 3

column_list = ['Value1', 'Value2']

master_list = []

for id in id_list:
    master_dict = {}
    for column in column_list:
        array_steps_id_df = array_steps_df.loc[array_steps_df['Id'] == id]
        array_steps_id_df = array_steps_id_df[[column]].values

        master_dict[column] = []

        for obs in range(len(array_steps_id_df)-step+1):
            start_obs = obs + step
            master_dict[column].append(array_steps_id_df[obs:start_obs,])
    master_list.append(master_dict)



for idx, dic in enumerate(master_list):
    # init arrays here
    if idx == 0:
        value1_array_init = master_list[0]['Value1']
        value2_array_init = master_list[1]['Value2']
    else:
        value1_array_init += master_list[idx]['Value1']
        value2_array_init += master_list[idx]['Value2']
        
value1_array = np.array(value1_array_init)
value2_array = np.array(value2_array_init)

all_array = np.hstack((value1_array, value2_array)).reshape((len(array_steps_df) - (step + 1), 
                                                             len(column_list),
                                                             step)).transpose(0, 2, 1)
```

Fixed, my mistake added a transpose at the end and redid order of features and steps in reshape.

Credit to this site for some extra help

https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-turn-pandas-data-frame-into-time-series-input-for-rnn/